# Load Data form script using AJAX or jQuery on page load

Tags: jquery, ajax

In wordpress widget area I have script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com/out/data_out.js.php?data=0"></script>
```

I need to load it using AJAX or jQuery (with loader animation) becouse site.com is very slow and delays the loading of the page. How I can do that?

I'm looking for any example...

Answer (score 0):

take a look at https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
Here should be all you need

Answer (score 0):

GET:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.site.com/out/data_out.js.php?data=0',
    type: 'GET'
})
.done(function(results){
    // do something with results
});
```

POST:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.site.com/out/data_out.js.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { data : 0 }
})
.done(function(results){
    // do something with results
});
```

Comment: "// do something with results" how to display result data?

Comment: It depends on what kind of data your `data_out.js.php` is outputting. A simple `alert(results)` will give you an idea. For JSON, most use something like `var result = $.parseJSON(results)`, or if you get HTML back, use `var result = $(results)` to create a jQuery object from the results.